# How do i make a rails collection generic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For a single object I was able to make it generic by doing f.object

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

which allowed my make my partial generic

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
```

how would i do a similar thing for any array, like these

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @all_items %>
```

so that in the partial i could reference it with my_item and not feed_item ?

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items, as: :feed_item %>
<%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @all_items, as: :feed_item %>
```

Comment: ok that answers my question but now i realize my question wasn't actually what i needed. How would i make just the array generic when not using a collection? <%= render 'shared/feed', @all_items%>  <%= render 'shared/feed', @feed items_items%>

Comment: I would like it to nest something like this <%= render 'shared/feed', :locals => { :the_items => @feed_items }%> with this inside <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: the_items, as: :my_item %>

Comment: What type of feed items do you have? Do all models within @all_items inherit from a common class?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4ad05f0162aecd2c5a13 Here is a gist. the issue is basically in static controller and home.html.erb. How do I turn '@user_items' in my if and '@all_items' in my else into generics to use in _feed.html.erb ?